# WebView no Android, modificando o HTML

Tags: java, android, webview

Estou conseguindo carregar o URL no meu dispositivo, usando o *WebView*, porém a página que carrega não é adaptada para dispositivos móveis. Gostaria de saber se tem como eu acessar a página, porém eliminando algumas partes do HTML.
Código abaixo:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button btEntrar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

myWebView.loadUrl("SITE");

btEntrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btEntrar);
}


private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("SITE DESEJADO")) {
        // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
        return false;
    }
    // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
}
```

Desejo deixar apenas o campo de login, senha e o botão de login, e depois passar adiante normalmente.

Comment: Boa! Também queria saber.

Comment: Acho que voce pode pegar o site com curl e depois salvar num arquivo externo na pasta `temp` ae vc carrega com `myWebView.loadUrl("/tmp/siteConvertido.html");`

Comment: O cUrl não seria um efeito de troca de página?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o método **loadData**. Para saber mais sobre o método **loadData** e também sobre outros métodos que podem ser usados em seu caso consulte a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Exemplo de uso:

```
webview.loadUrl("http://example.com/");

String example = "<html><body>My first body<b>LIKE</b> mee.</body></html>";
webview.loadData(example, "text/html", null);
```

- Exemplo de código disponível na documentação.

Abraços.